# Construction of disjoint sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Find a countable family $\left \{ D_{n} \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of disjoint set such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$ , where $\left \{ C_{n} \right \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ another family.

I constructed

$D_{1}=C_{1}$

$D_{2}=C_{2}\setminus C_{1}$

$D_{3}=C_{3}\setminus(C_{1}\cup C_{2})$

.

.

$D_{n}=C_{n}\setminus(C_{1}\cup ...\cup C_{n-1})$

Where $D_{i}\cap D_{j}=\varnothing$ for all $i\neq j$

But I dont know how to make the proof that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$ any advise will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $$D_n\subset C_n \implies \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$
Now if $$x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$ there exists $n_0$ such that, $x\in C_{n_0}$

Therefore the set 
$$A=\{p\in \Bbb N: x\in C_p \}\neq\emptyset$$

Let $$j =\min A$$ therefore $$ x\in C_j~~~~\text{and} ~~~x\notin C_i ~~i =1,2,\cdots j-1 \implies x\in D_j \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}.$$

Hence 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_{n}\supset\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$